# ListView fast scroll bars bug

Tags: android, listview, adapter, fastscroll, sectionindexer

I'm working on dictionary application. I have a listview with fast scroll enabled and adapter which implements SectionIndexer. When I'm working with chinese dictionary I have much more sections then when working with west-european languages and have a small issue:

> if I stop fast scrolling and while scroll bars are visible begin using
>   default scrolling my "fast scroll scroller" immideatly moves to
>   another position (somewhere at the top) and only when I'll get almost
>   to the end of the list it'll start moving to my position too with much
>   greater speed.

Is there a reason for such behaviour? If there any way to hide fast scroll bars when using default scrolling (but without disabling the fast scroll)?

Comment: I found that this bug is similar to http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33293 THe reason is wrong implementation of getSectionForPosition&getPositionForSection methods, but I simply don't understand how to implement htem right

Answer (score 0):

thought I'd post here in the hopes that it's not too late.

Note: This is not using an AlphabetIndexer, and I don't think using three collections to manage a list is a good idea, though it is simple, and explains the concept.

Below is a basic example of how to use the callbacks:

```
public LinkedHashMap<Integer,String> sectionList = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,String>();
public HashMap<Integer,Integer> sectionPositions = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
public HashMap<Integer,Integer> positionsForSection = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

When you have your "locations" array (pre-ordered), this will create three hashmaps to track things, really simple implementation, really easy to read :

```
 if( locations != null && locations.size() > 0 ) {
    //Iterate through the contacts, take the first letter, uppercase it, and use that as a key to reference the alphabetised list constructed above. 
    for( int i = 0; i < locations.size(); i++ ) {
        String startchar =locations.get(i).getStartCharacterForAlphabet();

        if( startchar != null ) {
            if( sectionList.containsValue(startchar) == false ) {
                sectionList.put(Integer.valueOf(i),startchar);
                positionsForSection.put(Integer.valueOf(sectionList.size() - 1), Integer.valueOf(i));
            }
        }

        sectionPositions.put(Integer.valueOf(i), sectionList.size() - 1);
    }  
}
```

And here are the three callbacks:

```
@Override
public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
    return positionsForSection.get(Integer.valueOf(section)).intValue();
}

@Override
public MyLocation getItem(int position) {
    if( locations.size() > position ) {
        return locations.get(position);
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
    return sectionPositions.get(Integer.valueOf(position)).intValue();
}
```

Hope it helps!